# Create a secondary axis in excel using charts

Tags: c#, excel

I try to create secondary axis in my excel chart from c#. I try this code-

```
    Excel.ChartObjects xlCharts = (Excel.ChartObjects)xlWorkSheet.ChartObjects(Type.Missing);
    Excel.ChartObject myChart = (Excel.ChartObject)xlCharts.Add(10, 80, 300, 250);
    Excel.Chart chartPage = myChart.Chart;

    chartRange = xlWorkSheet.get_Range("C2", GetLetterFromNum(columns.Length - 1 + Convert.ToInt32(NumCust.Text)) + Convert.ToString(rowIndex));
    TimeRange = xlWorkSheet.get_Range("A2", "A" + Convert.ToString(rowIndex));
    SecondryRange = xlWorkSheet.get_Range("B2", "B" + Convert.ToString(rowIndex));
    chartPage.SetSourceData(chartRange, misValue);
    chartPage.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = TimeRange;
    chartPage.SeriesCollection(1).YAxisType =   AxisType.Primary;
    chartPage.SeriesCollection(1).YAxisType = AxisType.Secondary;
```

but the complayer doesn't recognize the "AxisType" command,
but I always get error message

> The name 'AxisType' does not exist in the current context

I couldn't find what I do wrong...

Answer (score 0):

i found this post [at msdn](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4a6ecdcb-12f9-4e27-b8f4-785a66010a0b/c-automate-excel-chart-with-secondary-axis-generates-hresult-0x800a03ec-exception) where an example with a secondary axe is given